# ontouch method is null pointer exception my application touch in start button

Tags: android, android-view

class is RadarSceen then method ontouch method is crash is null pointer exception and this method use start radar and stop radar.then  localRotateAnimation.setDuration(3000L) crash is null pointer exception

```
public class RadarScreen extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private static final String APP_TAG = "com.example.ghostsam";
    private CountDownTimer countdownHideGhost = null;
    private CountDownTimer countdownShowGhost = null;
    private DisplayMetrics getDisplay = new DisplayMetrics();
    private int getDisplayHeight;
    private float getDisplayScale;
    private int getDisplayWidth;
    private Boolean hideGhosts = Boolean.valueOf(false);
    private ImageView ivLogo = null;
    private ImageView ivRadar = null;
    private ImageView ivRadarGhosts = null;
    private ImageView ivSignalButton = null;
    private Typeface layoutFontFace;
    private Boolean radarRun = Boolean.valueOf(false);
    //  private RotateAnimation rotateAnimation ;
    private RotateAnimation localRotateAnimation;
    private boolean settingsGeneralVibrate = true;
    private Boolean showGhosts = Boolean.valueOf(false);
    private int showGhostsZufallszahl = 0;
    private Vibrator vib = null;

    public Bitmap drawButton(String paramString1, String paramString2) {
        Bitmap localBitmap = Bitmap
                .createBitmap(this.getDisplayWidth - (int) (70.0F * this.getDisplayScale),
                        (int) (52.0F * this.getDisplayScale), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas localCanvas = new Canvas(localBitmap);
        Paint localPaint = new Paint();
        localPaint.setTypeface(this.layoutFontFace);
        localPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        localPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        localPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(paramString2));
        localCanvas.drawRoundRect(
                new RectF(0.0F, 0.0F, localBitmap.getWidth(), localBitmap.getHeight()), 12.0F,
                12.0F, localPaint);
        localPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        localCanvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(2.0F, 2.0F, -2 + localBitmap.getWidth(),
                -2 + localBitmap.getHeight()), 12.0F, 12.0F, localPaint);
        localPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(paramString2));
        localPaint.setAlpha(200);
        localPaint.setTextSize(32.0F * this.getDisplayScale);
        localPaint.setTextScaleX(1.75F);
        localPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        localCanvas.drawText(paramString1, localBitmap.getWidth() / 2,
                36.0F * this.getDisplayScale, localPaint);
        return localBitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap drawRadar(Boolean paramBoolean) {
        Bitmap localBitmap = Bitmap
                .createBitmap(-50 + this.getDisplayWidth, -50 + this.getDisplayWidth,
                        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas localCanvas = new Canvas(localBitmap);
        Paint localPaint = new Paint();
        int i = (int) ((localBitmap.getWidth() - 10.0F * this.getDisplayScale) / 2.0F
                + 5.0F * this.getDisplayScale);
        int j = (int) (i - 5.0F * this.getDisplayScale);
        localPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        localPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        localPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        localPaint.setStrokeWidth(3.0F * this.getDisplayScale);
        localPaint.setAlpha(75);
        for (int k = 0; ; k++) {
            if (k > 4) {
                localPaint.setAlpha(100);
                localPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                localPaint.setShader(new SweepGradient(i, i, 0, -16711936));
                if (paramBoolean.booleanValue()) {
                    RectF localRectF = new RectF();
                    localRectF.set(i - j, i - j, i + j, i + j);
                    localCanvas.drawArc(localRectF, 0.0F, 360.0F, true, localPaint);
                }
                localPaint.setShader(null);
                localPaint.setAlpha(255);
                localPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#810003"));
                localPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                localPaint.setStrokeWidth(0.0F);
                localCanvas.drawCircle(i, i, 10.0F * this.getDisplayScale, localPaint);
                return localBitmap;
            }
            localCanvas.drawCircle(i, i, j - k * 40 * this.getDisplayScale, localPaint);
        }
    }

    public Bitmap drawRadarGhosts(Boolean paramBoolean) {
        Bitmap localBitmap = Bitmap
                .createBitmap(-50 + this.getDisplayWidth, -50 + this.getDisplayWidth,
                        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas localCanvas = new Canvas(localBitmap);
        Paint localPaint = new Paint();
        if (paramBoolean.booleanValue()) {
            int i = (int) ((localBitmap.getWidth() - 10.0F * this.getDisplayScale) / 2.0F
                    + 5.0F * this.getDisplayScale);
            int j = (int) (i - 5.0F * this.getDisplayScale);
            localPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            localPaint.setAlpha(255);
            Random localRandom = new Random();
            localPaint.setAlpha(150);
            int k = localRandom.nextInt(180);
            int m = localRandom.nextInt(j);
            int n = i + (int) (Math.cos(3.141592653589793D * k / 180.0D) * m);
            int i1 = i + (int) (Math.sin(3.141592653589793D * k / 180.0D) * m);
            localPaint.setColor(-16711936);
            localPaint.setShader(
                    new RadialGradient(n, i1, 22.0F * this.getDisplayScale, -16711936, 0,
                            TileMode.CLAMP));
            localCanvas.drawCircle(n, i1, 15.0F * this.getDisplayScale, localPaint);
            if (localRandom.nextInt(50) < 5) {
                int i6 = localRandom.nextInt(180);
                int i7 = localRandom.nextInt(j);
                int i8 = i + (int) (Math.cos(3.141592653589793D * i6 / 180.0D) * i7);
                int i9 = i + (int) (Math.sin(3.141592653589793D * i6 / 180.0D) * i7);
                localPaint.setShader(
                        new RadialGradient(i8, i9, 22.0F * this.getDisplayScale, -16711936, 0,
                                TileMode.CLAMP));
                localCanvas.drawCircle(i8, i9, 15.0F * this.getDisplayScale, localPaint);
            }
            if (localRandom.nextInt(75) < 5) {
                int i2 = localRandom.nextInt(180);
                int i3 = localRandom.nextInt(j);
                int i4 = i + (int) (Math.cos(3.141592653589793D * i2 / 180.0D) * i3);
                int i5 = i + (int) (Math.sin(3.141592653589793D * i2 / 180.0D) * i3);
                localPaint.setShader(
                        new RadialGradient(i4, i5, 22.0F * this.getDisplayScale, -16711936, 0,
                                TileMode.CLAMP));
                localCanvas.drawCircle(i4, i5, 15.0F * this.getDisplayScale, localPaint);
            }
        }
        return localBitmap;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
        Log.i("com.example.ghostsam", "onStart RadarScreen");
        requestWindowFeature(1);
        getWindow().setFlags(1024, 1024);
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.radarscreen);
        SharedPreferences localSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("app_prefs", 0);
        int i = localSharedPreferences.getInt("appStartCounter", 0);
        int j = localSharedPreferences.getInt("appStartFirst", 0);
        int k = i + 1;
        SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor = localSharedPreferences.edit();
        localEditor.putInt("appStartCounter", k);
        if (j <= 0) {
            localEditor.putInt("appStartFirst", (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L));
        }
        localEditor.commit();
        if ((k == 5) || (k == 10) || (k == 25)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder localBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            localBuilder.setIcon(17301543);
            Resources localResources1 = getResources();
            Object[] arrayOfObject1 = new Object[1];
            arrayOfObject1[0] = "name";
            localBuilder.setTitle(localResources1.getString(R.string.app_name, arrayOfObject1));
            Resources localResources2 = getResources();
            Object[] arrayOfObject2 = new Object[1];
            arrayOfObject2[0] = "name";
            localBuilder.setMessage(localResources2
                    .getString(R.string.dialog_ratemarket_question, arrayOfObject2));
            Resources localResources3 = getResources();
            Object[] arrayOfObject3 = new Object[1];
            arrayOfObject3[0] = "name";
            localBuilder.setPositiveButton(
                    localResources3.getString(R.string.dialog_button_yes, arrayOfObject3),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface,
                                int paramInt) {
                            Resources localResources = RadarScreen.this.getResources();
                            Object[] arrayOfObject = new Object[1];
                            arrayOfObject[0] = "name";
                            Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                                    Uri.parse(localResources.getString(R.string.app_marketlink,
                                            arrayOfObject)));
                            RadarScreen.this.startActivity(localIntent);
                            paramDialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            Resources localResources4 = getResources();
            Object[] arrayOfObject4 = new Object[1];
            arrayOfObject4[0] = "name";
            localBuilder.setNegativeButton(
                    localResources4.getString(R.string.dialog_button_no, arrayOfObject4),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface,
                                int paramInt) {
                            paramDialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            localBuilder.create().show();
        }
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu paramMenu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.radarscreen, paramMenu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onError(Exception paramException) {
    }

    public void onIllegalHttpStatusCode(int paramInt, String paramString) {
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int paramInt, KeyEvent paramKeyEvent) {
        if (paramInt == 4) {
            quitApp();
        }
        for (int i = 1; ; i = 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem paramMenuItem) {
        switch (paramMenuItem.getItemId()) {
            default:
                break;
            case R.id.radarscreen_menu_moreapps:

                Resources localResources2 = getResources();
                Object[] arrayOfObject2 = new Object[1];
                arrayOfObject2[0] = "name";
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(localResources2
                        .getString(R.string.app_marketdeveloperlink, arrayOfObject2))));
                break;
            case R.id.radarscreen_menu_rateapp:

                Resources localResources1 = getResources();
                Object[] arrayOfObject1 = new Object[1];
                arrayOfObject1[0] = "name";
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(
                        localResources1.getString(R.string.app_marketlink, arrayOfObject1))));
                break;

            case R.id.radarscreen_menu_about:

                startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
                break;

            case R.id.radarscreen_menu_settings:

                startActivity(new Intent(this, Settings.class));
                break;
            case R.id.radarscreen_menu_quit:
                quitApp();
        }
        return true;
    }


    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("com.example.ghostsam", "onResume RadarScreen");
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(this.getDisplay);
        this.getDisplayWidth = this.getDisplay.widthPixels;
        this.getDisplayHeight = this.getDisplay.heightPixels;
        this.getDisplayScale = (this.getDisplayWidth / 480.0F);
        this.layoutFontFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        this.settingsGeneralVibrate = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext())
                .getBoolean("settings_general_vibrate", true);
        this.vib = ((Vibrator) getSystemService("vibrator"));
        this.ivLogo = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivLogo));
        this.ivLogo.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo),
                (int) (460.0F * this.getDisplayScale), (int) (68.0F * this.getDisplayScale),
                true));
        this.ivSignalButton = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivSignalButton));
        this.ivSignalButton.setImageBitmap(drawButton("start radar", "#005F21"));
        this.ivSignalButton.setOnTouchListener(this);
        this.ivRadar = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivRadar));
        this.ivRadar.setImageBitmap(drawRadar(Boolean.valueOf(false)));
        this.ivRadarGhosts = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivRadarGhosts));
        if (this.ivRadarGhosts != null) {
            this.ivRadarGhosts.setImageBitmap(drawRadarGhosts(Boolean.valueOf(false)));
        }
        this.countdownShowGhost = new CountDownTimer(15000L, 1000L) {
            public void onFinish() {
                RadarScreen.this.showGhosts = Boolean.valueOf(false);
                RadarScreen.this.hideGhosts = Boolean.valueOf(false);
                if (RadarScreen.this.countdownHideGhost != null) {
                    RadarScreen.this.countdownHideGhost.start();
                }
            }

            public void onTick(long paramLong) {
                Random localRandom = new Random();
                if (!RadarScreen.this.showGhosts.booleanValue()) {
                    RadarScreen.this.showGhosts = Boolean.valueOf(true);
                    RadarScreen.this.showGhostsZufallszahl = (1000 + localRandom
                            .nextInt(10000));
                    if (localRandom.nextInt(50) >= 10) {
                        AlphaAnimation localAlphaAnimation2 = new AlphaAnimation(0.0F, 0.975F);
                        localAlphaAnimation2.setDuration(1000L);
                        localAlphaAnimation2.setFillAfter(true);
                        if (RadarScreen.this.ivRadarGhosts != null) {
                            RadarScreen.this.ivRadarGhosts.startAnimation(localAlphaAnimation2);
                            RadarScreen.this.ivRadarGhosts.setImageBitmap(
                                    RadarScreen.this.drawRadarGhosts(Boolean.valueOf(true)));
                            if (RadarScreen.this.settingsGeneralVibrate) {
                                RadarScreen.this.vib.vibrate(20L);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ((RadarScreen.this.showGhostsZufallszahl > paramLong) && (!RadarScreen.this
                        .hideGhosts.booleanValue())) {
                    RadarScreen.this.hideGhosts = Boolean.valueOf(true);
                    AlphaAnimation localAlphaAnimation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.975F, 0.0F);
                    localAlphaAnimation1.setDuration(1000L);
                    localAlphaAnimation1.setFillAfter(true);
                    if (RadarScreen.this.ivRadarGhosts == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    RadarScreen.this.ivRadarGhosts.startAnimation(localAlphaAnimation1);

                }
            }
        };
        this.countdownHideGhost = new CountDownTimer(12500L, 2250L) {
            public void onFinish() {
                RadarScreen.this.showGhosts = Boolean.valueOf(false);
                RadarScreen.this.hideGhosts = Boolean.valueOf(false);
                if (RadarScreen.this.countdownShowGhost != null) {
                    RadarScreen.this.countdownShowGhost.start();
                }
            }

            public void onTick(long paramLong) {
            }
        };
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("com.example.ghostsam", "onStop RadarScreen");
        BitmapDrawable localBitmapDrawable1 = (BitmapDrawable) this.ivLogo.getDrawable();
        this.ivLogo.setImageBitmap(null);
        this.ivLogo.setImageDrawable(null);
        this.ivLogo = null;
        Bitmap localBitmap1 = localBitmapDrawable1.getBitmap();
        if ((localBitmap1 != null) && (!localBitmap1.isRecycled()))

        {
            localBitmap1.recycle();
        }

        BitmapDrawable localBitmapDrawable2 = (BitmapDrawable) this.ivRadar.getDrawable();
        this.ivRadar.setImageBitmap(null);
        this.ivRadar.setImageDrawable(null);
        this.ivRadar = null;
        Bitmap localBitmap2 = localBitmapDrawable2.getBitmap();
        if ((localBitmap2 != null) && (!localBitmap2.isRecycled()))

        {
            localBitmap2.recycle();
        }

        BitmapDrawable localBitmapDrawable3 = (BitmapDrawable) this.ivRadarGhosts.getDrawable();
        this.ivRadarGhosts.setImageBitmap(null);
        this.ivRadarGhosts.setImageDrawable(null);
        this.ivRadarGhosts = null;
        Bitmap localBitmap3 = localBitmapDrawable3.getBitmap();
        if ((localBitmap3 != null) && (!localBitmap3.isRecycled()))

        {
            localBitmap3.recycle();
        }
        BitmapDrawable localBitmapDrawable4 = (BitmapDrawable) this.ivSignalButton
                .getDrawable();
        this.ivSignalButton.setImageBitmap(null);
        this.ivSignalButton.setImageDrawable(null);
        this.ivSignalButton = null;
        Bitmap localBitmap4 = localBitmapDrawable4.getBitmap();
        if ((localBitmap4 != null) && (!localBitmap4.isRecycled()))

        {
            localBitmap4.recycle();
        }

        this.countdownHideGhost.cancel();
        this.countdownHideGhost = null;
        this.countdownShowGhost.cancel();
        this.countdownShowGhost = null;
        this.radarRun = Boolean.valueOf(false);
        this.showGhosts = Boolean.valueOf(false);
        this.hideGhosts = Boolean.valueOf(false);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
        switch (paramMotionEvent.getAction()) {
            default:
                if (paramView != this.ivSignalButton) {
                    break;
                }
            case 0:
                if (this.radarRun.booleanValue()) {
                    if (this.radarRun.booleanValue()) {
                        if (this.ivSignalButton == null) {
                            break;
                        }
                        this.ivSignalButton.setImageBitmap(drawButton("stop radar", "#1BA449"));
                    }
                }
            case 1:
                if (this.ivSignalButton == null) {
                    break;
                }
                this.ivSignalButton.setImageBitmap(drawButton("start radar", "#1BA449"));
        }

        // while (paramView != this.ivSignalButton);

        if (this.radarRun.booleanValue()) {
            if (this.ivSignalButton != null) {
                this.ivSignalButton.setImageBitmap(drawButton("stop radar", "#005F21"));
            }
            if ((paramMotionEvent.getX() <= 0.0F) || (paramMotionEvent.getX() >= paramView
                    .getWidth()) ||
                    (paramMotionEvent.getY() <= 0.0F) || (paramMotionEvent.getY() >= paramView
                    .getHeight())) {
                this.ivSignalButton.setImageBitmap(drawButton("stop radar", "#005F21"));
            }
            if (this.ivSignalButton != null) {
                this.ivSignalButton.setImageBitmap(drawButton("start radar", "#005F21"));
            }
            RotateAnimation localRotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0.0F, 360.0F, 1, 0.5F, 1,
                    0.5F);
            localRotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            localRotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
            localRotateAnimation.setRepeatMode(1);
            if (!this.radarRun.booleanValue()) {
                if (this.ivSignalButton != null) {
                    this.ivSignalButton.setImageBitmap(drawButton("stop radar", "#005F21"));
                }
            }
            this.radarRun = Boolean.valueOf(true);
            this.radarRun = Boolean.valueOf(false);
            if (this.ivRadar != null) {
                this.ivRadar.setImageBitmap(drawRadar(Boolean.valueOf(false)));
            }
            localRotateAnimation.setDuration(10L);
            localRotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
            if (this.ivRadarGhosts != null) {
                this.ivRadarGhosts.setImageBitmap(drawRadarGhosts(Boolean.valueOf(false)));
            }
            if (this.countdownHideGhost != null) {
                this.countdownHideGhost.cancel();
            }
            if (this.countdownHideGhost != null) {
                this.countdownShowGhost.cancel();
            }
        }

        if (this.ivSignalButton == null) {
            this.ivSignalButton.setImageBitmap(drawButton("start radar", "#005F21"));
        }
        if (this.ivRadar != null) {
            this.ivRadar.setImageBitmap(drawRadar(Boolean.valueOf(true)));
        }
        localRotateAnimation.setDuration(3000L);
        localRotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
        if (this.countdownHideGhost == null) {
            this.countdownHideGhost.start();
        }
        this.ivRadar.startAnimation(localRotateAnimation);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post logcat here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to problems here:

1. You defined a filed `RotateAnimation localRotateAnimation` but never assigned a value to it. That's why you get a NullPointerException.
2. You are using a local variable with the same name and assign it a value: `RotateAnimation localRotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0.0F, 360.0F, 1, 0.5F, 1, 0.5F);`. Most likly, you wanted to use the filed. So change that to just `localRotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(/*params*/);`

I'm not sure if fixing 2. fixes 1. because I did not understand your logic. Maybe 2. gets called every time before you reach the code which throws the NPE now.
Maybe you need to assign a value somewhere else to.

---

Maybe this code block is what you want:

```
    // moved up to run it even if condition is false
    // and use field
    localRotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0.0F, 360.0F, 1, 0.5F, 1, 0.5F);

    if (this.radarRun.booleanValue()) {
        if (this.ivSignalButton != null) {
            this.ivSignalButton.setImageBitmap(drawButton("stop radar", "#005F21"));
        }
        if ((paramMotionEvent.getX() <= 0.0F) || (paramMotionEvent.getX() >= paramView
                .getWidth()) ||
                (paramMotionEvent.getY() <= 0.0F) || (paramMotionEvent.getY() >= paramView
                .getHeight())) {
            this.ivSignalButton.setImageBitmap(drawButton("stop radar", "#005F21"));
        }
        if (this.ivSignalButton != null) {
            this.ivSignalButton.setImageBitmap(drawButton("start radar", "#005F21"));
        }
        localRotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        localRotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        localRotateAnimation.setRepeatMode(1);
        if (!this.radarRun.booleanValue()) {
            if (this.ivSignalButton != null) {
                this.ivSignalButton.setImageBitmap(drawButton("stop radar", "#005F21"));
            }
        }
        this.radarRun = Boolean.valueOf(true);
        this.radarRun = Boolean.valueOf(false);
        if (this.ivRadar != null) {
            this.ivRadar.setImageBitmap(drawRadar(Boolean.valueOf(false)));
        }
        localRotateAnimation.setDuration(10L);
        localRotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
        if (this.ivRadarGhosts != null) {
            this.ivRadarGhosts.setImageBitmap(drawRadarGhosts(Boolean.valueOf(false)));
        }
        if (this.countdownHideGhost != null) {
            this.countdownHideGhost.cancel();
        }
        if (this.countdownHideGhost != null) {
            this.countdownShowGhost.cancel();
        }
    }

    if (this.ivSignalButton == null) {
        this.ivSignalButton.setImageBitmap(drawButton("start radar", "#005F21"));
    }
    if (this.ivRadar != null) {
        this.ivRadar.setImageBitmap(drawRadar(Boolean.valueOf(true)));
    }
    localRotateAnimation.setDuration(3000L);
    localRotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
    if (this.countdownHideGhost == null) {
        this.countdownHideGhost.start();
    }
    this.ivRadar.startAnimation(localRotateAnimation);
```